# Why does my PSD file contain only one layer after saving a project from Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, pdf, save, configuration

I have saved a brochure for print and because of the file size issues I saved my original Photoshop file as a `PDF` without Photoshop editing capabilities.

Then I applied some changes and saved as Photoshop again - ONLY to have it open up later and only have one layer. As this happened to me before, I checked it today and it did the same thing, now I still have the file open in Photoshop with all layers intact, but when I "save as" `PSD` under a different name and open it up again it only gives me one layer!

**How can I use the `Save As...` function in Photoshop and still keep all of my layers intact and unflattened?**

Answer (score 3):

If you are saving as a native Photoshop file, **Ensure the Layers options is checked** in the save dialog window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the function "Save a copy...". If that doesn't work - save it as a .PSB file, then back to .PSD

Comment: Thank you Henrik! I finally figured it out - before loosing my head. When you click 'save as' below where you put in your file name and type of file you want to save it as there is a bunch of tick boxes, so I just ticked the 'layers' tick box (which gave me a yellow attention notice in any case) ... and voila!!! Everything is back to normal! Yay!